# Excel Export Classic Ap Leading Zeros

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to add the leading zeros to my excel export file but it keeps removing my zeroes.

```
dteThisDob = rs("dob")
strThisDobYear = year(dteThisDob)
strThisDobMonth = right("0" & month(dteThisDob),2)
strThisDobDay = right("0" & day(dteThisDob),2)
strDob = strThisDobMonth & strThisDobDay & strThisDobYear
```

This give me the output in excel 3041975.
What I'm looking for is 03041975

Comment: If you examine `strDob` does it contain the leading zero?  If it does, then you need to tell Excel to treat that value as a string.

Comment: Yes it does @RonRosenfeld anyway how I can do that

Comment: Cannot help you with that.  I am not familiar with your tools, and you don't show how you are getting the data into Excel.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I just writing the data to a .xls file

Comment: Then you can either pre-pend the string with a single quote (you will see that in the formula bar, but not in the cell), or format the column as text before you write the data.

Comment: Mine show up in the cell when I use that @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Are you sure you are using the single quote `'` and not the back quote? `

Comment: The single quote is called a `prefixCharacter`, and I believe the only variables that can affect this are whether or not Lotus navigation is enabled.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I used the prefix

Comment: @RonRosenfeld " ' "-& strDob & --This is what I did  and I get '03041975

Comment: If you look at the formula bar, not the cell, do you see one apostrophe or two single apostrophes?

Comment: I just see one @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Wierd.  With regard to that cell, what is returned if in some other cell you type `=CODE(cell_reference)` where cell_reference is the cell containing this string.

Comment: I get 39 @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Hmm. There's something going on that I clearly do not understand. Can you upload a stripped down version of the workbook (with no sensitive information) that demonstrates the problem (to some public sharing site) and post a link here?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld done

Comment: I don't see the link to a workbook, only a screenshot.

Comment: Oh this is very sensitive data, everything is sensitive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223182/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-sdot2323).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Excel to not convert strings to numeric values (and by doing so removing the leading zeros) by prefixing them with a **TAB** character.

```
strDob = Chr(9) & strThisDobMonth & strThisDobDay & strThisDobYear
```